# Как получить значение из бд в скрипте. Django

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно получить `key` из базы данных `Users` и с этой переменной уже работать.
Я попробовал вот такой код:

```
@login_required()
def index(request):
    key_user = Users.objects.filter(name=request.user)
    for key_user in key_user:
        key = key_user['key']

    # worlds = World.objects.get(key_user=key)
    return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

Но он не сработал с ошибкой

```
TypeError at /app/
'Users' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def index(request):
    key_user = Users.objects.filter(name=request.user)
    for h in key_user:
        key = h.key
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]